# CMAKE install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I am looking for the method to solve this error, and I have been searched one in this web site, seems the same error occurred again, **I was try the way to solve the error which is mentioned by the author like this:**

> Blockquote

changing this:

```
INSTALL(

  TARGETS lemon

  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib

  COMPONENT library

)
```

to this:

```
INSTALL(

  TARGETS lemon

  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib

  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib

  COMPONENT library
)
```

> Blockquote

the section of "LIBRARY DESTINATION XXX" in my "Makefilelist.txt" is already there, that means i can not solve the error by using this method. **so how can I do for fix this error and why this error happen?**

besides: the error turn up when I complies the "TagLib" project which is an open source project for process music media tag, my CMake version is 3.9.1 and the TagLib version is 1.11.1, the make tool is linked to "mingw32-make", i want to using the TagLib in Qt (Qt creator version 4.3.1 Qt core version 5.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

i have been complied under qt using the tutorial with https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/ thanks Joel Verhagen.