# INSTALL TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION

Tags: c++, cmake

On my ubuntu 18.04 this file (https://github.com/andrewkatson/supercop/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt)  works perfectly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(monero-crypto)
enable_language(ASM C)
include(intree.cmake)

add_library(monero-crypto $<TARGET_OBJECTS:monero-crypto-intree>)

INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/monero/crypto/${MONERO_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}.h" DESTINATION "include/monero/crypto")
INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/monero/crypto.h" DESTINATION "include/monero")
INSTALL(TARGETS monero-crypto ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

I have also tried the original way the file was setup.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(monero-crypto)
enable_language(ASM C)
include(intree.cmake)

add_library(monero-crypto $<TARGET_OBJECTS:monero-crypto-intree>)

INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/monero/crypto/${MONERO_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}.h" DESTINATION "include/monero/crypto")
INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/monero/crypto.h" DESTINATION "include/monero")
INSTALL(TARGETS monero-crypto LIBRARY)
```

However, on a fresh ubuntu 18.04 ec2 instance this file fails with the following error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION for static library target
  "monero-crypto".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I saw this [CMAKE install TARGETS given no ARCHIVE DESTINATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952280/cmake-install-targets-given-no-archive-destination) but the solution is specific to them.

You have to do the following commands in that directory to reproduce

```
cmake .
```

My ubuntu has cmake version 3.16.3
the ec2 has cmake version 3.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file needed to look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(monero-crypto)
enable_language(ASM C)
include(intree.cmake)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
add_library(monero-crypto $<TARGET_OBJECTS:monero-crypto-intree>)

INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/monero/crypto/${MONERO_CRYPTO_LIBRARY}.h" DESTINATION "include/monero/crypto")
INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/monero/crypto.h" DESTINATION "include/monero")
INSTALL(TARGETS monero-crypto ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```